LWC Tabset - edit size of lightning-tab
I have a question on LWC Lightning-tabset that provided by SF as below figure.
I just curious that is it possible to change size of each tab? because if you see in below figure, the tab's area of 'Item One' and 'Item Two' is much smaller than 'Item Three'.
Can we make it having the same size?


No, this is not possible. First of all, there is no respective option in the documentation you're pointing out. There are neither any respective styling hooks listed in the context of the Lightning Design System documentation.
In terms of CSS, the necessary change appears to be minuscule however: a single width: 33% on each tab (for example) would do. The deployed HTML of the tabset is some ul, some li and some a. So if one insists on the feature, utilizing the HTML of the afore mentioned Lightning Design System page is straightforward. Here's a minimal POC.
Enclosing LWC HTML
<template>
    <c-scaled-lightning-tab-set tabs={tabs}></c-scaled-lightning-tab-set>
</template>

Enclosing LWC Javascript
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class TabSetTester extends LightningElement {
    tabs = [
        {label: 'Item One', content: 'One Content !'},
        {label: 'Item Two', content: 'Two Content !', title: '2nd tab extended title'},
        {label: 'Item Three', content: 'Three Content !'}
    ];
}

Custom Tabset LWC HTML
<template>
    <div class="slds-tabs_default">
        <ul class="slds-tabs_default__nav" role="tablist">
            <template for:each={_tabs} for:item="tab">
                <li class={tab.classes} title={tab.title} role="presentation" key={tab.label} 
                    data-tab-value={tab.label} onclick={handleTabClick} style={style}>
                    <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0)" role="tab" 
                        tabindex="0" data-tab-value={tab.label}>{tab.label}</a>
                </li>
            </template>
        </ul>
        <div class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-show" role="tabpanel">
            {selectedTab.content}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

Custom Tabset LWC Javascript
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

const INACTIVE_TAB_CLASSES = 'slds-tabs_default__item';
const ACTIVE_TAB_CLASSES = 'slds-tabs_default__item slds-is-active';

export default class ScaledLightningTabSet extends LightningElement {

    @api tabs;
    
    _tabs;
    selectedTab;

    get style() {
        return `width: ${100 / this.tabs.length}%`;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this._tabs = this.tabs.map(tab => Object.assign({classes: INACTIVE_TAB_CLASSES}, tab));
        this._tabs[0].classes = ACTIVE_TAB_CLASSES;
        this.selectedTab = this._tabs[0];
    }

    handleTabClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.selectedTab.classes = INACTIVE_TAB_CLASSES;
        this.clickedTabValue = event.target.getAttribute('data-tab-value');
        this.selectedTab = this._tabs.find(tab => tab.label === this.clickedTabValue);
        this.selectedTab.classes = ACTIVE_TAB_CLASSES;
    }
}

